# Как найти все значения многомерного массива по названию ключа

Tags: php, массивы

Допустим есть многомерный массив и мне нужно собрать в новый массив все id`шники.

Мой вариант:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $newArray[] = $value['id'];
}
```

Но возможно есть более лаконичный вариант ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Jack'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Tom'],
    ['id' => 456, 'name' => 'Maria']
];

print_r(array_column($array, 'id'));
```